# Same MDI Form for nested forms

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have a MDI form (Main Software Form "Form_Main" ) which has Menustrip.

Clicking a menu to open Search form "Form_Search" using following code:

```
// From the Main Form
Form_Search frm = new Form_Search();
frm.MdiParent = this;
frm.Show();
```

When the user selects a desired result, a details form "Form_Details" should be opened to show the information of the selected result. Opening the details for is done using the following code:

```
// From the Search Form
Form_Details frm_det = new Form_Details(selectedID);
frm_det.Show();
```

But the details form "Form_Details" is out of the MDI space.

My question is how can I open the details form "Form_Details" from the search form "Form_Search" but still under the MDI form "Form_Main"

Thanks for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the MDI Parent of the new form to the same, main parent:

```
Form_Details frm_det = new Form_Details(selectedID);
frm_det.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
frm_det.Show();
```

Comment: Thanks, works great !! , but I can't vote it up because of my new reputation rate. but really thanks for your help